# how to take two buttons diffrent value by calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getValue(){

 var v = document.getElementById("btn2").value;
 document.getElementById("display").value += v;

}
```

```html
        <input type ="text" id = "display" value = "" ></input>
<tr>
                <td>
     <input type = "button" id = "btn2" value="7" onclick="getValue(this)" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type = "button" id = "btn2" value="8" onclick="getValue(this)" ></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> I just want to different value by clicking 8 or 7 button. but every time i got 7 as result what can i do please help.. and more i want to pass "this" in getValue(this) so that by clicking that button get the all information that buttton. plz help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs, in dom should be unique. jQuery is returning only the first element when calling $('#idstring'); as document.getElementById('#idstring') also does.

In this case, you could use className.

You also pass a parameter to the function, but you don't use it.

I edited this snippet to show how to bind this to the function before calling it. Like this, you can use 'this' if it's your thing.

```js
function getValue(el) {
  document.getElementById("display").value = el.value;

}

function getValue2() {
  document.getElementById("display").value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="display" value=""></input>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="button" class="btn2" value="7" onclick="getValue(this)"></input>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" class="btn2" value="8" onclick="getValue2.bind(this)()"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: if i want to pass "this" in my function parameter like  getValue(this) //get all value

Comment: If you pass "this" each time you call the funciton, like in your exemple, it's ok.
You don't pass "this", but you can bind it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your ids are unique.
2. Make use of the argument (`this`) that you are passing.

```js
function getValue(button){

 var v = document.getElementById(button.id).value;
 document.getElementById("display").value += v;

}
```

```html
        <input type ="text" id = "display" value = "" ></input>
<tr>
                <td>
     <input type = "button" id = "btn1" value="7" onclick="getValue(this)" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type = "button" id = "btn2" value="8" onclick="getValue(this)" ></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have answers to your question. However a cleared way might be to use classes.

```
$(".my_buttons").click(function(){
    $("#display").val($(this).val());
});

<input type="text" id="display" />
<input type="button" class="my_buttons" value="7" />
<input type="button" class="my_buttons" value="8" />
```